# Explanation request for flashes of light

Tags: home-experiment, vision, perception

I have observed what I believe to be the same phenomenon on two occasions and wanted to ask for possible explanations. Both times, I saw flashes of whitish light, near the ceiling of a room. They lasted only a small fraction of a second. They were not that bright: like a lamp turning on and off. They were in a part of the ceiling where there are no sources of light.

My guess: some unequal electrical charges in the air discharging. I haven't heard of this happening just randomly, powerfully enough that it can be seen.

(Potentially) Relevant details:
1) The first time, my girlfriend and I both saw and remarked on the flash at the same time. This is my only evidence that it wasn't just physiological.
2) Both flashes took place in Michigan. The second was in the bathroom of a heated university building during cold weather. I don't remember the circumstances of the first exactly, but I think it was in the living room of an air-conditioned house during the summer.

Thanks for any possible explanations. I'm not a physics student or anything, this is really just a curiosity for me. Also when I try to google this I only run into "paranormal phenomena" websites. :)

Also I'm not sure what tag to use, so people should feel free to change tags if there are more relevant ones.

Comment: I don't know what it *is* but I'm fairly confident it *isn't* "unequal charges in the air discharging". The dielectric breakdown of air is about 3 million volts/metre. The best typical static discharge can manage is small sparks across gaps less than a centimetre.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too broad, lacks data, and calls for speculation.

Comment: Interesting events, but unfortunately we probably won't be able to help with this without more info, so sadly this will probably remain as an unexplained happening. I also doubt it's static.

Comment: @BrandonEnright: Those things are true; I posted it anyway because the physics.stackexchange tour encourages asking about "Explanations of observed physical or astronomical phenomena." As for speculation, I would welcome it in this case; I'm just looking for possibilities.

Comment: @dgh: Good to know, thank you. The only other possibility I could think of offhand was build-up and ignition of some gas, but that seems unlikely (and dangerous!).

Comment: It still could be physiological (retinal flashes, e.g.) and just a coincidence that on one occasion you and your GF saw a flash about the same time. (Coincidences lead to a belief that an otherwise unremarkable event had meaning)  Another likely possibility: some external flash which, reflected off various objects, made its way thru a window and onto your ceiling.

Comment: @RobSilversmith I'm all for speculation about what it could be and making a list of possibilities.  This site just isn't the right venue for it.

Comment: My first guess would be a reflection of light in some other place, or perhaps some sort of [mirage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirage) (although that seems a stretch to me). However I also agree with @BrandonEnright that this isn't really the right venue for this speculation.

Comment: IMHO, instead of lack of data there is clear observation of two separate events that are unusual. Two separate observers were involved (and he didn't say, they were both under the influence) so it can't be chalked up to perception. The question raised deserves to be thought about and labeling it speculation simply limits exploration.

Comment: My first guess would be that you have some electronic device in the room, which briefly flashed an LED. For example, an incoming message on a phone that's set to silent. Because LEDs are quite directional, if it was aimed at the ceiling it might look like light coming from the ceiling rather than the device.

Answer (score 0):

Coincidence but it's possible that you had something either outside the house or even inside, moving and possibly with a mirror like surface and what you saw was a reflection.

I saw something similar once and resolved the puzzle to a Christmas ornament hanging outside, turning just right at one point to reflect light from the Sun.